# Given the ID of a product in woocommerce, how can I get its URL?

Tags: plugins

Say I have the ID of a product in wooCommerce; can I generate its URL somehow? (example /shop/fresh-apples)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Products in WooCommerce are a custom post type, so this should work:

```
$url = get_permalink( $product_id );
```

You can treat that `$product_id` as a postID (that's what it is), so you can use it with other normal WP functions, like:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'">'.get_the_title($product_id).'</a>';
```

Comment: How can I change the permalink, so it automatically adds it to the cart?

Comment: I found `add_to_cart_url()` does what I asked above.